# Saving more than one pictures AND also videos on android. Possibly using intent_action_still_image_camera

Tags: java, android, camera

I'm currently using ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE, but I cannot save more than one picture at a time and also I can't take video (for that i should use ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE). I've seen some codes, where they use INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA and then broadcast reciver, but they were outdated. I need help please! Thanks

Comment: Use CameraX or another camera library (Fotoapparat, CameraKit-Android, etc.) and take the pictures directly from your own app, if you need that level of control.

Comment: But if I create my own camera app, it'll never be good for all devices, as the default one is.

Comment: The authors of those libraries would disagree with your opinion. Moreover, what you are proposing will "never be good for all devices". There is no requirement for a device to have an app that supports `INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA`. There is no requirement for that app to save images or videos anywhere that your app can access them, particularly on newer versions of Android. And, there is no requirement that there be any way that you can reliably detect when those images or videos are saved.

Comment: And what about a broadcast reciver?

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand that question.

Comment: From what I read is a sort of listener whitch can tell me if the camera button is pressed while the app is running, so I can then copy and paste the saved image in the new folder.

Comment: "can tell me if the camera button is pressed while the app is running" -- very few phones have a physical camera button. A camera app does not need to use an on-screen button as the trigger mechanism, nor does it have to broadcast anything when that button is clicked. And a camera app does not have to save its image to a file on the filesystem where your app can access it.